# make configure Makefile on windows

Tags: makefile

im using windows there i have download git library using `git clone` command.[git library](https://github.com/attie/libxbee3) [documentation](http://attie.co.uk/libxbee/getting_started/os/windows/win8.1_x64#s3) That library has a makefile.

1. i installed GNU make (GnuWin32)
2. i gave filepath cd `<makefilepath>` cmd
3. type **make configure**

i'm having following Errors. Any help is appreciated.thank you.

```
C:\Users\venushka\Desktop\libxbee3>make configure
    process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.
    process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.
    make/os_detect.mk:13: make/os.windows.mk: No such file or directory
    makefile:29: make/build.generic.mk: No such file or directory
    make: *** No rule to make target `make/build.generic.mk'.  Stop.
```

Comment: There is no `make` program in off-the-shelf ms-windows. You'll have to install some development tools set. There are several different ones available. Describing the pros and cons of each would take too long.

Comment: @RolandSmith i installed GNUWin32 . could you please be kind enough to see my problem. i have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the 'win32' branch. I'll update the documentation to make this step more prominent.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the `make` directory in the `libxbee3` repository, you'll see that there is no file called `os.windows.mk`.
The build system was written with UNIX-like systems in mind because the  `make` program *is* the standard build system on UNIX-like operating systems.

As mentioned in the documentation that you referenced, on ms-windows you have to build it with the microsoft "visual studio" tools.

Comment: could you please explain me more to build it with the microsoft "visual studio" tools. this is the first time i use git library. thank you so much.

Comment: Follow the instructions in the `libxbee3` documentation. Since I don't use windows, I cannot be more specific.